# Is there a way to turn off result sets for stored procs?

Tags: mysql

Please consider the following snippet of MySQL stored procedure code which works fine...

```
BEGIN
sponsor: loop
    -- DO STUFF

    select @sq := sq from a_nice_table where id = @a_nice_var;

    -- DO MORE STUFF
end loop sponsor;
END
```

The line of code where I populate the variable 'sq' is the source of my question. This stored procedure code is being written to "DO STUFF" and NOT to be returning results.  I need to populate the variable, but returning the @sq in a result set is undesired.

I am using Navicat to code with, and I get a result set returned for each loop iteration.

Is there a way to turn off result sets for stored procs?  Is there also a way turn turn them back on mid-process?  That would be useful for debugging purposes.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way of populating doesn't output result.

```
select sq into @sq from a_nice_table where id = @a_nice_var limit 1;
```

It works for multiple variables, too

```
select sq, whatever, one_more into @sq, @v_whatever, @v_one_more from a_nice_table where id = @a_nice_var limit 1;
```

> The INTO clause can name a list of one or more variables, which can be user-defined variables, stored procedure or function parameters, or stored program local variables.

Read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html).

P.S.: Note, that I added `LIMIT 1` to the queries. Otherwise an error would be thrown that the query returns more than one row. The difference to

```
select @sq := sq from a_nice_table where id = @a_nice_var;
```

is, that the `@sq := sq` is done for every row (if there are multiple), but in the end the variable will hold the value of the last row, not of all rows. So actually there's no difference, resultset-wise...

Comment: Great answer!  Code works, well written answer, and a link to help me help myself further.  Perfection, thank you.